# Retrieve data from MySQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a MySQL database but when I execute the php page it shows a white page. Any idea if and what I do wrong...

> ```
> $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES");
> while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));
> {
>  $Ssn=$row['Ssn'];
>  $UnionMembershipNumber=$row["UnionMembershipNumber"];
>  $fname=$row['Fname'];
>  $surname=$row['Surname'];
>  $StreetName=$row['StreetName'];
>  $StreetNumber=$row['StreetNumber'];
>  $PostalCode=$row['PostalCode'];
>  $Salary=$row['Salary'];
>  echo $fname."".$surname."".$StreetName."".$StreetNumber."".$PostalCode."".$Salary."<br>";
> }
> ?>
> ```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Remove the `;` at the end of the while

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
...
```

Comment: If he does have a mysql_select_db and a connection yes, you are right

Comment: Thank you all, the ; and the root password of database was the problem :P

Answer (score 2):

you made the mysql_connect(); and mysql_select_db(); correct?

Answer (score 2):

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query));
{
```

Remove the `;`.

Also, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the beginning of the code for debugging.

Answer (score 1):

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { // no semicolon

would not hurt, try print_r ($query); before while loop to make sure that you got results, and make sure that your mysql_connect() and mysql_select_db() did not fail.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array() will fetch both an enumerated and associative array in one, so you don't have to specify the MYSQL_ASSOC.  mysql_fetch_assoc() will fetch just the associative array, and mysql_fetch_row() will fetch just the enumerated array.